# How can we use google pay API in our website?

Tags: javascript, api, payment, google-pay, upi

Like I added the code but it is working on mobile phone only. But, when I am using the same code on my laptop browser, it is showing Google pay is not install.

Which means that it is looking for google pay app.

The website is running in India only.

Is there any way I can use it on my desktop too? Any resource will be good related to this integration.

I have searched a lot, and even google dev docs is not completely understandable.

```
/**
 * Read the amount from input form.
 */
function readAmount() {
    // return parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);
    return 1;
}

/** Launches payment request flow when user taps on buy button. */
function onBuyClicked() {
    if (!window.PaymentRequest) {
        console.log('Web payments are not supported in this browser.');
        return;
    }

    const supportedInstruments = [{
        supportedMethods: ['https://tez.google.com/pay'],
        data: {
            pa : 'example@icici',
            pn : 'example ',
            tn : 'Example Pay',
            mc : 5943,
            tr : (Math.random().toString(10).slice(2)).toString()+'UPI',
            tid : (Math.random().toString(10).slice(2)).toString(),
            url : 'url-for-site',
        },
    }];

    const details = {
        total: {
            label: 'Total',
            amount: {
                currency: 'INR',
                value: new Number(String(readAmount())),
            },
        },
        displayItems: [{
            label: 'Original Amount',
            amount: {
                currency: 'INR',
                value: new Number(String(readAmount())),
            },
        }],
    };

    const options = {
        requestShipping: false,
        requestPayerName: false,
        requestPayerPhone: false,
        requestPayerEmail: false,
        shippingType: 'shipping',
      };

    let request = null;
    try {
        request = new PaymentRequest(supportedInstruments, details, options);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Payment Request Error: ' + e.message);
        return;
    }
    if (!request) {
        console.log('Web payments are not supported in this browser.');
        return;
    }

    var canMakePaymentPromise = checkCanMakePayment(request);
    canMakePaymentPromise
        .then((result) => {
            showPaymentUI(request, result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error calling checkCanMakePayment: ' + err);
        });
}

/**
 * Show the payment request UI.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {PaymentRequest} request The payment request object.
 * @param {Promise} canMakePayment The promise for whether can make payment.
 */
function showPaymentUI(request, canMakePayment) {
    if (!canMakePayment) {
        handleNotReadyToPay();
        return;
    }

    // Set payment timeout.
    let paymentTimeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.clearTimeout(paymentTimeout);
        request.abort()
            .then(function () {
                console.log('Payment timed out after 20 minutes.');
            })
            .catch(function () {
                console.log('Unable to abort, user is in the process of paying.');
            });
    }, 20 * 60 * 1000); /* 20 minutes */

    request.show()
        .then(function (instrument) {
            window.clearTimeout(paymentTimeout);
            processResponse(instrument); // Handle response from browser.
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

/** Handle Google Pay not ready to pay case. */
function handleNotReadyToPay() {
    alert('Google Pay is not ready to pay.');
}

/* Converts the payment response into a JSON string.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {PaymentResponse} paymentResponse The payment response to convert.
 * @return {string} The string representation of the payment response.
 */
function paymentResponseToJsonString(paymentResponse) {
    // PaymentResponse is an interface, JSON.stringify works only on dictionaries.
    var paymentResponseDictionary = {
        methodName: paymentResponse.methodName,
        details: paymentResponse.details,
        shippingAddress: addressToJsonString(paymentResponse.shippingAddress),
        shippingOption: paymentResponse.shippingOption,
        payerName: paymentResponse.payerName,
        payerPhone: paymentResponse.payerPhone,
        payerEmail: paymentResponse.payerEmail,
    };
    return JSON.stringify(paymentResponseDictionary, undefined, 2);
}

/**
 * Process the response from browser.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {PaymentResponse} instrument The payment instrument that was authed.
 */
function processResponse(instrument) {
    var instrumentString = instrumentToJsonString(instrument);
    console.log(instrumentString);

    fetch('/buy', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }),
            body: instrumentString,
        })
        .then(function (buyResult) {
            if (buyResult.ok) {
                return buyResult.json();
            }
            console.log('Error sending instrument to server.');
        })
        .then(function (buyResultJson) {
            completePayment(instrument, buyResultJson.status, buyResultJson.message);

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Unable to process payment. ' + err);
        });
}

/**
 * Notify browser that the instrument authorization has completed.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {PaymentResponse} instrument The payment instrument that was authed.
 * @param {string} result Whether the auth was successful. Should be either
 * 'success' or 'fail'.
 * @param {string} msg The message to log in console.
 */
function completePayment(instrument, result, msg) {
    instrument.complete(result)
        .then(function () {
            console.log('Payment completes.');
            console.log(msg);
            document.getElementById('inputSection').style.display = 'none'
            document.getElementById('outputSection').style.display = 'block'
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML =
            JSON.stringify(instrument, undefined, 2);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

// Global key for canMakepayment cache.
const canMakePaymentCache = 'canMakePaymentCache';

/**
 * Check whether can make payment with Google Pay or not. It will check session storage
 * cache first and use the cache directly if it exists. Otherwise, it will call
 * canMakePayment method from PaymentRequest object and return the result, the
 * result will also be stored in the session storage cache for future usage.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {PaymentRequest} request The payment request object.
 * @return {Promise} a promise containing the result of whether can make payment.
 */
function checkCanMakePayment(request) {
    // Check canMakePayment cache, use cache result directly if it exists.
    if (sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty(canMakePaymentCache)) {
        return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(sessionStorage[canMakePaymentCache]));
    }

    // If canMakePayment() isn't available, default to assume the method is
    // supported.
    var canMakePaymentPromise = Promise.resolve(true);

    // Feature detect canMakePayment().
    if (request.canMakePayment) {
        canMakePaymentPromise = request.canMakePayment();
    }

    return canMakePaymentPromise
        .then((result) => {
            // Store the result in cache for future usage.
            sessionStorage[canMakePaymentCache] = result;
            return result;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error calling canMakePayment: ' + err);
        });
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/overview

Comment: I am using it in India, so I followed this https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/web/googlepay-business documentation.

Comment: OK, so I guess only an Indian can help - sorry about that

Comment: Using UPI with PaymentRequest is only available on mobile devices (Android).

Comment: just want to confirm is this free service by google or we need to pay extra per transaction ? can any please confirm this ?